# How to make an incremental backup with rsync from ext4 to xfs network drive?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, rsync

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.
I try to make an incremental backup of some files on my Ubuntu HD (ext4) to a Buffalo network HD (XFS).

My script mounts the Buffalo HD with this command :

```
sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.12/Sauvegardes /mnt/Sauvegardes -o username=myusername,password=mypassword
```

After the disk is mounted, I use rsync trying to make an incremental backup with **rsync** and **--link-dest**. Each day, when the script is launched, all the folders change according to actual date of the day. Here is an example when the script is launched on 2017-03-09. It should check on 2017-03-08 backup if files already exist :

```
sudo rsync -arR --link-dest="/mnt/Sauvegardes/racine_2017-03-08" --timeout=30 /home/flooder/Sauvegardes/ /mnt/Sauvegardes/racine_2017-03-09/
```

The problem : **rsync doesn't seem to check on the --link-dest destination. It copies all the files all the day. So the disk will be full quickly and the backup is very very long each day...**

Would you have an idea for me?
Should I mount the network drive an other way?
Do I have the right rsync command?

Comment: Maybe http://rsnapshot.org/ is an option for you.

Answer (score 0):

I have mounted my network disk with this line instead. It works well now. If the file already exists in --link-dest, only an hard link is created. Second pass is very very quick!

sudo mount -t cifs //192.168.1.12/Sauvegardes /mnt/Sauvegardes -o username=myusername,password=mypassword,uid=1000,gid=1000

uid and gid are those of my logged user.